# Очень легкий вопрос, слово в предложном падеже!

Tags: падежи

```
Выполнял задание из учебника, и после заглянул в ответы, где было указание, что мой ответ не правильный, хотя я больше чем уверен!
И.п роща
Р.п рощи
Д.п роще
В.п рощу
Т.п рощей
П.п роще (в учебнике дано: рощи)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существительные 1 склонения в предложном падеже имеют окончание Е. *О роще.*  Если в учебнике по-другому - выбросьте учебник! (Даже если это "просто" опечатка, кто знает. сколько их ещё. В хороших учебниках такого быть не должно!)

Comment: спасибо! Учебник - Ахременкова Л.А. К пятёрке шаг за шагом 2-4 классы
страница 270 =)

Answer (score 0):

Да, с таким учебником к пятёрке точно не дойдёшь! Остаётся внимательно слушать учителя на уроках.